# Puzzle of the day

Tags: logical-deduction

The aim is to draw a single contiguous line from the upper left corner to the lower right corner. The line includes each number from 1 to 39 exactly once.

[image]

CSV:

```
 1,25,23,12,31, 3,20, 2,15,13,19,23
36,22,28,27,32, 4,19,21,20,11,29,12
34,13, 7,23,19, 8, 2,11,36, 8, 2, 3
 7,24,38,29,23,19,27,17,37,14,11, 7
 2,23,21,30, 6,20,38, 6,28, 9,33, 8
28,13, 9,11,36,18,16,15,11,18,34,14
 1,36,11, 2, 9,14,19,35,38,25,20, 7
20,21,33, 8,15,23,20,29,30, 5,32,18
10,34, 7,26,13,34,21,35, 9,13,16,17
15,37,23,22,24,18,24,37,29,24,26,10
31, 3,34, 8,27, 7,37,15,20,21,23,35
 7,29,17,14,26,23,24,18,36,20,19,39
```

Comment: Starting from top left, can I go directly to 22, or must I go through one of 25 or 36?

Comment: 25 or 36 only...

Comment: "Contiguous" might be a better word than "continuous" for us math people. Graph search algorithms can readily solve this if you represent this grid as graph, checking conditions of being at the bottom right and the current path containing all aforementioned digits.

Comment: I changed continuous to contiguous

Comment: Do you have a text transcription of this puzzle? I'd like to solve this in a spreadsheet, but transcribing the digits would be tedious.

Comment: @Deusovi I have added CSV format.

Comment: Are you sure [logical-deduction] is accurate? I've been at this for about half an hour and haven't found *any* logical path anywhere at all -- only case-bashing.

Comment: I looked at naive brute force. I looked at rules among the adjacent numbers within the grid. I looked at simulated annealing (this got the closest). I looked at two different graph representations, and also found searching within them intractable. I looked at the grid and different representations of it as heatmaps/images. I looked at adapting Dijkstra's algorithm to dynamically recalculate weights, and same for A*.

Comment: I guess I could try turning this into naive bayes or MCMC simulation, but I feel I've put enough effort into this puzzle to ask that the OP gives us a hint.

Comment: I agree with @Deusovi, this requires a lot of guesswork. Highlighting the numbers that that occur less than four times will reveal likely portions of the path, even a few cells with certainty, but I don't see any logical solution for the complete path.

Comment: @Galen A simple depth-first search will suffice. Just avoid paths with duplicate numbers, and check that the endpoint is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution to the puzzle:

> [image]

Comment: Welcome! Can you perhaps provide a picture to show the path through the grid?

Comment: I just realized the reason why my simulated annealing approach got so close but couldn't finish was because my cost function punished internal nodes in the path from being adjacent to any number of nodes not equal to 2.

Answer (score 1):

My solution so far (incomplete). 
Eight more numbers to go (2,7,12,14,17,21,33,37):

> [image: Puzzle 1-39 partial solution]